# Integrate Zoho rest API's

Tags: rest, zoho, zohobooks

I am trying to integrate **Zoho rest API's** to achieve below list of tasks.

**Task List:**

a) To get Project List
b) To get Projects's Users list
c) To get List of Task for the projects
d) To Create new task

I have successfully generated access token by following [this](https://www.zoho.com/projects/help/rest-api/get-tickets-api.html#useAPI).

AccessToken and refresh token:

```
{
    "access_token": "1000.53ea059005781cfc.ff08c750c671f7d1267e6de1e",
    "refresh_token": "1000.2a5ddc41fb6faccb42.b6c01194764f259049187f",
    "api_domain": "https://www.zohoapis.com",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3600
}
```

When i try [get all portals operation](https://www.zoho.com/projects/help/rest-api/get-tickets-api.html), it gives me error like "Invalid OAuth access token." in the Postman.

[image: Postman]

In [Documentation](https://www.zoho.com/projects/help/rest-api/portals-api.html) not much more details like what is request, what is URL etc given.

How can I send a correct request to Project List or Projects's Users list?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, Have you added the scope "ZohoProjects.portals.READ", when you are generating the grant token.. ?

Comment: Hi @ManushVenkatesh,
Thanks for your reply. I have resolved by adding scope for Portal and regenerate access token when it expires.again thanks for the useful information

Comment: Hi @ManushVenkatesh,
Have you tried creation of task in Zoho API Integration? In this, Document upload is not working for me, but task is created successfully. can i get any information regards the same?

Comment: Hi @Justin, Yes, I've tried it.. Using below API, you can add attachments to the tasks..
https://www.zoho.com/projects/help/rest-api/tasks-api.html#add-attachments

Comment: Hi @ManushVenkatesh,

Thanks for the useful information.As per your suggestion, it will make 2 api calls right? one for task Creation and another for attachment. but they provide option to upload document while creating task(In a single call).

Comment: Hi @ManushVenkatesh,
Can you please share me code base. i am struggling to fetch attachment comes from RESTClient (Postman) into API.Awaiting for your response.